# Django: Need to check POST request mime type before uploading it to S3

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

So, here's my basic problem. I have form in my frontend that posts a file to my Django backend. Django will then pass that file off to AWS S3 for storage. I need to verify the file is a PDF or DOC before uploading to S3. I thought to check it's mime type with [python-magic](https://pypi.org/project/python-magic/) like so,

```
form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

if form.is_valid():
     mime_type = magic.from_buffer(request.FILES['file'].read(), mime=True)
     
     if mime_type in ALLOWED_MIMETYPES:
          upload(request.FILES['file'], file_name)
```

where upload just basically wraps [boto3's upload_fileobj](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_fileobj) method. However, according to [this Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57549343/why-does-request-filesfile-open-is-none-though-request-files-file-nam), the *.read()* I use in *magic.from_buffer()* empties the file buffer, so that when I pass the file into the upload method, it no longer exists.

I've tried using [copy and deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) to duplicate the file before checking it's mime type and then passing the duplicate into the upload function, but copy and deepcopy don't seem to work with fileobjects, as the duplicate is also empty after calling *.read()* on the original.

How can I copy the file passed through the POST request so that I can check its mime type before passing it to S3 for storage? Is there another way to check it's mime type that doesn't involve emptying the file buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

if form.is_valid():
    mime_type = magic.from_buffer(request.FILES['file'].read(), mime=True)
    request.FILES['file'].seek(0)

    if mime_type in ALLOWED_MIMETYPES:
        upload(request.FILES['file'], file_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

if form.is_valid():
    file = request.FILES['file']
    sio = BytesIO(file)

    mag = magic.Magic(mime=True)
    sio.seek(0)
    sio.content_type = mag.from_buffer(sio.read())

    if sio.content_type not in ALLOWED_MIMETYPES:
        sio.seek(0)
        upload(sio, file_name)
```